# MongoDB Method not supported

Tags: mongodb

I have a complex query in which I will pull articles from table from multiple companies and then group by on company id and then order each set based on lastupdated/published date and then take top 2 per company/set.
Apparently, it is throwing error and I don't want to use asenumerable() as it is a very big table and I don't want data to load into memory.
Here is the query:

```
var articles = (from article in collection.AsQueryable()
                                    where companyIds.Contains(article.CompanyId)
                                    where article.Active
                                    group article by article.CompanyId
                            into companyArticles
                                    select (from a in companyArticles
                                            orderby a.PublicationDate descending
                                            select a).Take((int) maxPerCompany)
                            ).SelectMany(a => a)
                            .OrderByDescending(a => a.PublicationDate)
                            .Skip(checked((int) skip))
                            .Take(checked((int) length))
                            .ToList();
```

// or linq

```
var companiesArticles = collection.AsQueryable()
                            .Where(c => companyIds.Contains(c.CompanyId) && c.Active)
                            .GroupBy(a => a.CompanyId, (a, records) =>
                                records.OrderByDescending(a => a.PublicationDate).Take((int) maxPerCompany))
                            .SelectMany(a => a)
                            .OrderByDescending(a => a.PublicationDate)
                            .Skip(checked((int) skip))
                            .Take(checked((int) length))
                            .ToList();
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Exception Message:
The method OrderByDescending is not supported in the expression tree: {document}.OrderByDescending(a => a.PublicationDate).

Exception Stack Trace:
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.BindMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.Bind(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.BindPipeline(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.BindMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.Bind(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.EmbeddedPipeline.EmbeddedPipelineBinder.Bind(Expression node, IBindingContext parent)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.SerializationBinder.BindEmbeddedPipeline(MethodCallExpression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.SerializationBinder.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.SerializationBinder.Visit(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.Pipeline.MethodCallBinders.SelectBinder.Bind(PipelineExpression pipeline, PipelineBindingContext bindingContext, MethodCallExpression node, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.MethodInfoMethodCallBinder`1.Bind(PipelineExpression pipeline, TBindingContext bindingContext, MethodCallExpression node, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.BindMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.Bind(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.BindPipeline(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.BindMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.Bind(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.BindPipeline(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.BindMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.Bind(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.BindPipeline(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.BindMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.Bind(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.BindPipeline(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.BindMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.Bind(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.Pipeline.PipelineBinder.Bind(Expression node, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.Prepare(Expression expression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.Translate(Expression expression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.Execute(Expression expression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryableImpl`2.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at

Comment: Please post the error message you are getting.

Comment: [Exception Message] The method OrderByDescending is not supported in the expression tree: {document}.OrderByDescending(a => a.PublicationDate).

Comment: [Source]: MongoDB.Driver